# Start ZNC, error: 'Found old config from ZNC < 0.203. Saving a backup of it'

Tags: linux, irc-bouncer

When i start ZNC, i tried all possible settings, nothing helps and i have a fatal error:

```
sudo systemctl status znc.service
jun 14 01:50:33 user-desktop systemd[1]: Started ZNC, an advanced IRC bouncer.
jun 14 01:50:34 user-desktop znc[1305]: Checking for list of available modules...
jun 14 01:50:34 user-desktop znc[1305]: Opening config [/var/lib/znc/configs/znc.conf]... [ ZNC is already running on this config. ]
jun 14 01:50:34 user-desktop znc[1200]: Found old config from ZNC < 0.203. Saving a backup of it.
jun 14 01:50:34 user-desktop znc[1200]: Creating a config backup... [ File exists ]
jun 14 01:50:34 user-desktop znc[1200]: You must define at least one user in your config.
jun 14 01:50:34 user-desktop znc[1200]: Unrecoverable config error.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your have broken packages, try reinstalling znc from user `root` using the commands:

```
sudo apt remove znc ; reboot

# apt install znc

# apt upgrade ; reboot

sudo systemctl status znc.service
```

I think this is the only method that solves this problem.